# How to show the negative values when generating a range of numbers between 2 numbers in c programming

Tags: c, loops

The task is to ask a user to input 2 values (say m and n) wherein these values may be positive or negative. The program should generate the numbers from n to m such that the interval is 1. Ex, if m = -3 and n = 4, the numbers generated are -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, however when i use my code, it will only show the positive values.   Thank you!

```
int
main ()
{
    int m, n, i; 
    scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);

    for ( i = 0; i <= m || i <= n; i++)
        printf("%d", i);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int m, n, i, min, max;
scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);
if (m < n) {
    min = m;
    max = n;
}
else {
    min = n;
    max = m;
}

for (i = min; i <= max; i++)
    printf("%d", i);
```

Comment: im sorry, what V are you talking about?

Comment: @jay: The V next to the answer which solves your problem, as you just stated above!

Answer (score 0):

```
int
main ()
{
    int m, n, i; 
    scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);

    for ( i = m; i <= n; i++)
        printf("%d ", i);

    return 0;
}
```

Assuming that `m` is the lower boundary, you have to start your loop from `i=m`.